# Azure scheduled always on

Tags: azure

Is it possible with Azure to schedule the feature **Always on** on my Web App?.

I realized my invoice went up a lot because I had turn on the option to always have the server On, but I want to know if is possible to have the server from 7am-12m always on , and the remaining time just turn on the server when needed.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please edit your question to clarify what you're asking (as the question stands now, it runs the risk of being closed as 'unclear what you're asking')? That is: Are you referring to Virtual Machines? Web/worker role instances? Web app? And what exactly do you mean by "always on" ? (again, please edit your question; don't post clarifications in comments).

Comment: @DavidMakogon, I added web app on my question.

Comment: It's still not clear what you're attempting to do. I'm assuming you're running a web site with visitors. If you're doing something different (e.g. periodic scheduled tasks), that's something different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Web Apps, Always On means your app stays loaded in memory, vs being aged out (which prevents long delays when a user first visits after the app's cache has expired). It's not related to the allocated Web App resources being deployed. If you have an App Service Plan (and it's not at Free tier), you're paying for it.

With Web Apps, you can start and stop individual web apps under the app service plan, but you cannot just stop the app service plan. The ways to reduce cost-burn:

- scale back number of instances
- scale back size of instances
- scale back service tier (you can go as low as Shared and still use custom domain name, with higher tiers required for SSL)